# How to use redux toolkit query without React hooks

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit

I have created this mutation in redux toolkit query and now I have to call this mutation endpoint in vanilla Javascript file. How to do this?

```js
import { apiSlice } from "apiHelpers/ApiSlice";

const placeMyOrder = apiSlice.endpoints.placeMyOrder.initiate();

export const PLACE_order = async () => {
  const { data } = await placeMyOrder(orderobj);
  if (data) {
   
  } else {
    
    return;
  }
};
```

Comment: You just need to dispatch the `initiate` action to the store, e.g. `store.dispatch(apiSlice.endpoints.placeMyOrder.initiate())`. See [Usage without React Hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/usage-without-react-hooks) for more details. Basically the first two lines of Julien's answer below, the rest seems irrelevant.

Comment: this [github issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3575#issuecomment-1620453479) might helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initiate` is thunk it needs to be dispatched to work. It's better to use hooks except you have particular reasons like server side rendering for example.

Here is how to use your [query without hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/usage-without-react-hooks):

```js
import { apiSlice } from "apiHelpers/ApiSlice";
 
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ orderInfo }) => {
      const { data: order } = await
          store.dispatch(
              apiSlice.endpoints.placeMyOrder.initiate(orderInfo)
          ); 

      return {
        props: {
          order,
        },
      };
    }
);
```

Here is how to do it with redux toolkit query and hooks:

```js
import { apiSlice } from "apiHelpers/ApiSlice";

// It's better to do it where you api is then export usePlaceMyOrder
const { usePlaceMyOrder } = apiSlice

export const PlaceOrder: FC<Props> = ({ orderInfo }) => {
  const {
    data: order,
    isFetching,
    isLoading,
  } = usePlaceMyOrder(orderInfo, {
    pollingInterval: 0,
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
    skip: false,
  })

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>
  if (!order) return <div>Missing order!</div>

  return (
    <div>
      {order.name} {isFetching ? '...refetching' : ''}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Inside the component, the `usePlaceMyOrder` hook is called with two arguments: `orderInfo` (which is passed to the component) and an options object. This hook probably initiates an API request to place an order with the given id and returns the request's status and response data.

- The options object sets a pollingInterval of 0 milliseconds, meaning the API request will not be repeated every XX milliseconds.
- refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true means that the hook will re-run the API request whenever the component mounts or the `orderInfo` argument changes.
- skip: false means that the API request will not be skipped. You can set it to true when you do not want to do the API call yet

[here is how to dive more into RTKQ](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview)